# Why does 2-3 prompts appear before even printing console.log output?

Tags: javascript

```js
let yourName = prompt("Enter name");

console.log(`Just a test ${yourName}`);
console.log("Welcome to the test. Please enter your username: ");

let username = prompt("Enter username");
```

when i run this javascript code, there are 2 prompts at the same time and then the console.log is printed. How do I make it work so first prompt yourName appears and then console.log lines are printed in console and then it asks for username after a few seconds?

or is there any way to accept input in Console itself instead of prompts?

Comment: Have you tried or heard using timeout? This can help your issue. with this you can also set how long will the timeout take.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(`Just a test ${prompt('your name')}`);
console.log(`Welcome to the test. Please enter your username: ${prompt('your username'}`);
```

Comment: Nope. Still not working. 2 Prompts at the same time and then it displays console.log

Comment: after the first console.log:

if(username){
put your second console.log
}

Comment: As soon as I run the code, 2 prompts are at the same time and then it displays whatever is written

Comment: using your original code, after you do let username = prompt and then the first console.log, put the condition:
if (yourName){
then your second console.log output
} 

That should have it so the username only prompts if the "yourName" prompts first

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var name = prompt("Enter name:");
    console.log('Test name: '+name);
    console.log("Welcome to the test.");
    var userName = prompt('Enter username:');
    console.log('Test username: '+userName);

function myPrompt() {
  var username = prompt('Enter username:')
  console.log('Test username: '+username);
}
    window.setTimeout(myPrompt, 3000);
```

Is this something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout` with below sample:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  function timeoutFn() {
    $timeout(function() {
      let username = prompt("Enter username");
      console.log(`Your username is: ${username}`);
    }, 1500);
  }

  let yourName = prompt("Enter name");
  console.log(`Just a test ${yourName}`);
  console.log("Welcome to the test. Please enter your username: ");
  timeoutFn();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method to execute a function after the timer expires. The following code will display the `username` prompt after 2000 ms.

```js
var username;

function usernamePrompt() {
   username = prompt('Enter username:')
   console.log(`username: ${username}`);
}

let yourName = prompt("Enter name")

if (yourName) {
    console.log(`Just a test ${yourName}`);
    console.log("Welcome to the test. Please enter your username: ");
    window.setTimeout(usernamePrompt, 2000);
}
```